# when click on folder print only that folder of images in php?

Tags: php

How to display folder and when click on folder disply that folder of images?

```
  <?php
$directory = "*/";
$images = glob($directory . "*.jpg");

foreach($images as $image)
{
    echo '<img src="'.$image.'"/>'."<br><br>";
  //echo $image;
}
?>
```

Comment: Well, you make an anchor (`<a>` tag) pointing to some script of yours. Either hard coded or handed over as a parameter you define which folder to display. Then you output the files found in that folder, just as you tried above. Most likely it makes more sense to rely on a read-to-use gallery script, though.

Answer (score 0):

**Use glob this way**

```
$dirname = "media/images/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");
foreach($images as $image) {
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" /><br />';
}
```

Comment: i used it but the problem is- it have 3 folders or many and that folder will display on web page then i will select any folder and then display images. so not able to do it please advise1